# How to make part of href act like a link in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From response I got data's so I map these data on table and in response data link inside string like
Messsage: "to display please <url with ahref is here">Click."
when I list that data it shows as string it doesnt act like a link

thank you...

```
<TableBody>
                                    {error ? (
                                        <TableRow>
                                            <TableCell colSpan={5} align="center">{error}</TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    ) :  data.map((item) => {
                                        return (
                                            <TableRow key={item.Id} >
                                                <TableCell>{item.Message}</TableCell>
                                            </TableRow>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </TableBody>
```